# Allow SELECT on specific column only

Tags: mysql, permissions

I have a `User` table with 3 column; `name, email, password`, etc.

I would like to create another user that can only `SELECT` the `name` column.

```
SELECT name     FROM User;    -- Ok!
SELECT email    FROM User;    -- Not Ok!
```

Can this be done on MySQL?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For this you need to grant select permission to **user (MySQL User)** on that particular column of table.

```
GRANT SELECT (name) ON MyDb.User TO 'MySQLUser'@'MySQLHost';
```

For explanation have a look at [MySQL Documentation on column Privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-column-privileges)

Answer (score 4):

It would typically be better to use a view to hide columns as needed and then GRANT permissions on the view.

This decouples the table structure and permssions. If you change the table or recreate it, permissions will be lost. Or add a new column that now need separate permissions.

a.k.a add some views to simplify the permission set hierarchy.

Comment: Views make more troubles than solve: replication, backups, RDS.